# Как правильно реализовать функцию Выбор языка

Tags: android

Подскажите как правильно и лучше реализовать функцию выбора языка,есть приложения и выбор языка?

Comment: Локализация через strings.xml не подходит?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид если через String , то придется прописывать условия на нажатия выбранного языка в каждом классе ?

Comment: Нет, вам надо читнуть. Ваше приложение само будет подтягивать нужный язык, который соответствует локали девайса. вот доки https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html